# Keras hyperparameter tuning with hyperas using manual metric

Tags: python, keras, hyperparameters

I'm using the [hyperas document example](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) to tune the network parameters but based on f1 score instead of accuracy.

I'm using the following implementation for f1 score:

```
from keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.
        Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.
        Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many relevant items are selected.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall

    def precision(y_true, y_pred):
        """Precision metric.
        Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.
        Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many selected items are relevant.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision
    precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

with updating the metric parameter for compile function in following code line:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
                  optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})
```

to

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[f1],
                  optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})
```

the above metric works perfectly without using hyperas, while when I try to use it with the tuning process, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 96, in <module>
    trials=Trials())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py", line 67, in minimize
    verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py", line 133, in base_minimizer
    return_argmin=True),
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 367, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 385, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 244, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 218, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 137, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 840, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "D:\path\temp_model.py", line 86, in keras_fmin_fnct
NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you sure the function `f1()` is accessible to `model`? Just check if they are in the same class if there are any classes. If possible post more of the code.

Comment: All of the code is in the mentioned example .. Complete example section.

Comment: Can you please post your call to `optim.minimize()`?

Comment: @Amw5g what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the code example you linked to, you are not making hyperas aware of the custom f1 function.  The package author provides an [example to do that](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/examples/hyperas_in_intermediate_fns.py), as well.

In short, you need to add an additional `functions` argument to your `optim.minimize()` call.  Something like

```
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
     data=data,
     functions=[f1],
     algo=tpe.suggest,
     max_evals=5,
     trials=Trials())
```

I actually just implemented it today, so I'm confident you can get it working, too :)

Comment: is there a documentation for hyperas ?

Comment: @Minion I've used a combination of the github repo (particularly the issues section) and a number of different web articles/blog posts.  I don't see a full-on manual for hyperas.  Probably because it's just a thin wrapper for the bigger hyperopt library(which does have manuals).
Some posts I've used to help me include:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-an-efficient-way-to-build-neural-network-architectures-part-i-hyper-parameter-8129009f131b
https://medium.com/@hwu4/tips-for-hyperas-a058b27b8aa6
https://statisticalinterference.wordpress.com/2017/06/15/hyperas-for-lstms/